# Destroy/ Leave Action Mode on Screen Rotation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I have a ListFragment with a MultiChoiceModeListener for a Contextual Action Mode. After a long click the items get selected. However: If I rotate the screen the selection gets lost, BUT Android stays in the Action Mode. This means: You can still select the actions on the specific items you selected before the screen rotation.

I would like to leave the action mode after the screen rotation. Just showing the normal OptionsMenu. Seems harder than it sounds. I have tried those in onCreate():

- invalidateOptionsMenu()
- getListView().clearChoices();

Unfortunately nothing from above works.

Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The way to exit an `ActionMode` is to call `actionMode.finish()`.

Unfortunately, you only get a reference to the `ActionMode` in `onItemCheckedStateChanged`, so you will have to leak it up to the `Activity`. Then, the `Activity` can decide to finish it in `onStop/onDestroy` or `onConfigurationChange` (depending on whether you're handling config changes).

It's not elegant but it's the best I can come up with right now.

EDIT: 
Actually, you have a different problem - why is the ListView not remembering its selection?

Try to do no initialization if `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate` is not null (i.e., let the ListView restore its state) and see what happens then.

Comment: I figured out, that I used the wrong List-Layout. Now I am using simple_list_item_activated_1 and the ListView remembers its state. I can live with (indeed I prefer) this solution. :)